# stop rendering UIImage when scrolling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I saw a library in github the other day that basically won't do anything on the main thread, for example rendering an image if the user is still scrolling. Does anyone know what this library is? If not how can I do this easily? I am not asking on how to load images asynchronously. That part is done. Although images are loaded asynchronously the rendering of the image is still the issue that causes scrolling to be laggy. So I basically wanted to wait until the scroll stops to display the image.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the library you are after:

https://github.com/amrzagloul/AsyncImageView